# what are the proper stages for Gitlab CI/CD for a maven deploy?

Tags: maven, gitlab-ci

I am using Gitlab CI/CD for a Java/Maven project and am confused by the many examples which show multiple stages, where each stage calls a specific Maven phase (e.g. clean, compile, test, install)

The maven documentation is very clear that each phase implicitly invokes all prior phases.  So my question is, why do the examples not just invoke the last phase listed in the stages?  For example, if the last non manually-invoked stage in the yml does an 'mvn install', why not just have that be the sole stage in the yml?  It seems it is just a waste of CPU and time since the install will also call 'clean, compile, test, which have already all been called as part of the previous stages in the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

The "tutorials" that advice you to first call `mvn compile` then `mvn test` etc. have not understood the Maven lifecycle.

Just call **one** command, like `mvn install` for installing or `mvn deploy` if you want to deploy it with the help of Maven to some Maven repository.

Comment: Thank you.  What you are saying makes sense.  it is just odd since some of the examples I mentioned come straight from GitLab's technical writers:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-examples/maven/simple-maven-example

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for running different maven goals in different stages is clarity.

If a test fails and the pipeline has one job which runs `mvn deploy` you need to take a look at the logs why the pipeline failed.
But if a separate job exists where `mvn test` is executed you see at a glance that the pipeline failed because of tests.

In the example from the gitlab documentation they use cache to cache the output of `mvn compile` so the maven goals in the next steps don't compile from scratch but use the cache instead.

Comment: First there are not running goals. There are running life cycles and those separations do not make sense and showing that the understanding of Maven's life cycle does not exist. You can see in the output if a test fails etc. Apart from that  separating things like suggested you will run several things double etc.